Why does udev rule work just once for a random serial USB device node out of series?
I have a multiport USB-to-UART device based on CH348 chip running an out-of-kernel driver taken from https://github.com/WCHSoftGroup/ch9344ser_linux
The driver creates 8 character device nodes (/dev/ttyCH9344USB0 .. /dev/ttyCH9344USB7).
The device doesn't provide a serial number in the USB device descriptor, but there is an EEPROM that I want to read from the device, extract the serial number from there and use it to create a symlink like /dev/ttyUSB.CH348.<serial_number>.<instance>.
I've created a simple udev rule and put it into /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules:
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="*ttyCH9344USB*", OPTIONS="log_level=debug", PROGRAM="/usr/local/bin/ch34x_serial %E{DEVNAME}", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB.CH348.$result"

The rule does work as expected, but only for ONE single RANDOM node out of 8.
I have actually tried multiple various match rules, and regardless of what method I use (kernel name, usb attributes, etc.), if it matches, it does so only for ONE single RANDOM instance of the series. It may create me a symlink for instance 3, or 6, or 7, or any other, but just for a single ONE.
I've checked journalctl and udevadm monitor -p, and I found out that there are exactly 8 different add events coming to udev when I load the driver module. All of the events are identical except for the KERNEL, DEVPATH, SEQNUM and MINOR properties, and look like this:
KERNEL[706136.962119] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3.2/1-1.1.3.2.1/1-1.1.3.2.1:1.0/tty/ttyCH9344USB0 (tty)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3.2/1-1.1.3.2.1/1-1.1.3.2.1:1.0/tty/ttyCH9344USB0
SUBSYSTEM=tty
DEVNAME=/dev/ttyCH9344USB0
SEQNUM=26571
MAJOR=168
MINOR=0

I don't understand why only one of those actual events triggers the rule, whereas if I run udevadm test for any of the 8 device nodes, the rule works just fine for any and all of them.
It looks like udev is caching the action somehow and discards the "duplicates", although I don't understand how it comes to that conclusion.
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 Server with udev version 255.4-1ubuntu8.4.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

udev is probably running the program ch34x_serial 8 times in parallel. If
the program is communicating with the same device each time, some of the
replies may be lost or the device may not reply. Try adding code in the
program to ensure access is serialised. A simple way to do this is to use
flock to wait for a lock on the program file itself:
PROGRAM="flock /usr/local/bin/ch34x_serial /usr/local/bin/ch34x_serial %E{DEVNAME}"

It appears that you're right. I've replaced the call to ch34x_serial with a script that outputs random numbers taken from /dev/urandom, and voila! I got all 8 devices successfully. Will dig further into it. Thanks for the hint.

As it turned out, udev was running my ch34x_serial program 8 times in parallel, as pointed out by @meuh in their comment. Apparently, the driver doesn't tolerate that for EEPROM access operations.
To overcome that, I've added a simple synchronization based on a shared semaphore to serialize communication with the underlying EEPROM. I suppose I could instead patch the ch9344_linux driver but modifying the userspace program seemed easier.
Anyone in need to solve the same problem of connecting multiple CH348 devices to one machine are welcome to try the modified tool available at https://codeberg.org/AlexanderAmelkin/ch34x_serial
The modifed version coupled with a simple udev rule (also available from the above repository) works fine for me and produces 8 separate device aliases.
